# adobe Site Catalysts (ADBMobile) - trackAction extras not seen in report suite

Tags: ios, adobe-analytics

I am doing the following call in iOS to do a trackAction:

[ADBMobile trackAction:state data:params];

so the actual call looks like this:
  NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary
                                   dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"toggleSwitch status" : rememberuserID? @"on":@"off"}];
 [ADBMobile trackAction:@"toggleSwitch" data:params];

the issue is only the state is showing in the backend omniture.  That means im seeing toggleSwitch but not the params info called toggleSwitch status. Why is this ? With Track State it works fine.

Comment: i don't really know iOS / SDK syntax but a random shot in the dark: you have `@"toggle Switch` (with a space) and then later `@"toggleSwitch"` (no space). Perhaps this is somehow relevant? e.g. not referencing the right thing in the SDK? Not mapping the right thing in Adobe Mobile Services / Processing Rule?

Comment: I updated the code sorry about the typo